# How to run a GitHub Actions workflow for "push" or "pull_request" events, but not both

Tags: github-actions

I have a workflow with the following event triggers:

```
on:
  # workflow_dispatch: {}
  push:
    branches: "*"
  pull_request:
    branches: "*"
```

The workflow includes several jobs of which one them should only run for `pull_request`.

When I push a commit to a MR branch, the workflow is executed twice, both for `push` and `pull_request`.

Is there any way to tell GitHub Actions that the workflow should only run for `push` events, if it's not a MR branch?

Comment: What's a "MR branch"? You can specify _"pushes to X branch and updates to pull requests targetting X branch"_, which wouldn't trigger duplicates (as I do e.g. [here](https://github.com/textbook/build-info/blob/48c998f1159537d1ff3a91ea3aa9b66880c4ead2/.github/workflows/push.yml#L3-L8)) but you've explicitly made both run on all branches (which is the default anyway).

Comment: did you already check the https://github.com/fkirc/skip-duplicate-actions ?

Comment: The skip duplicate action is great! I recommend it. You could eventually use the [concurrency field](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/using-concurrency#example-using-concurrency-and-the-default-behavior) at the workflow level as well, to guarantee only the latest run is taken into consideration (and the previous ones cancelled).

Comment: @jonrsharpe - Your example runs for both `pull_request` and `push` events `main`? You don't run it for other branches?

Comment: @jonrsharpe How would you define it, if you want to run the workflow for `push` events to any branch, unless it also has open merge requests? In GitLab, I would create a rule like `$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH && $CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS`. Here the latter variable is truthy, when the branch has open merge requests

Comment: Why don't you just run `on: push:` for all branches and **not** `pull_request`, then? You're only getting duplicates because you're asking for builds on pushes to all branches **and** updates on pull requests _to_ all branches. _"You don't run it for other branches?"_ - in that example, no, but it's just to show the pattern.

Comment: If you still want to maintain both triggers, you would probably have to check those rules in a "setup" job and save those values as output to use them in the `if` condition of the following jobs, that would only run if those rules are valid.

Comment: Also discussed: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/26276. There's no context here on what you're trying to run, but maybe the PR-specific job could even be separated out.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, but if I have a workflow with `on.pull_request.branches: ["main"]` and another workflow that I want to run for all `push` events (`on.push.branches: "*"`), unless the former workflow was triggered, how would I define that? In GitLab, this is possible using `workflow.rules`

Comment: Any push to PR branch, will both trigger `pull_request` and `push` events, which will trigger multiple workflows